# Python: Getting option from function?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scope

I'm working with Tkinter in Python and am using OptionMenu and want to get the selection the user makes.

```
ex1 = StringVar(root)
ex1.set("Pick Option")
box = OptionMenu(root, "one","two","three", command=self.choice)

def choice(self,option):
   return choice
```

It work when I just do:

```
print choice
```

But I though I could somehow return it and then store it in a variable. For example, at the start of the code I made:

```
global foo
foo = ""
```

and then tried:

```
def choice(self,option):
   foo = option
   return foo
```

But this didn't work. Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but not sure it is what you wanted.

```
from Tkinter import StringVar
from Tkinter import OptionMenu
from Tkinter import Tk
from Tkinter import Button
from Tkinter import mainloop

root = Tk()
ex1 = StringVar(root)
ex1.set("Pick Option")
option = OptionMenu(root, ex1, "one", "two", "three")
option.pack()


def choice():
    chosen = ex1.get()
    print 'chosen {}'.format(chosen)
    # set and hold using StringVar
    ex1.set(chosen)
    root.quit()
    # return chosen


button = Button(root, text="Please choose", command=choice)
button.pack()
mainloop()
# acess the value from StringVar ex1.get
print 'The final chosen value {}'.format(ex1.get())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get what this is doing but when "return chosen" is called, I wish to assign that to a variable outside the scope of that function if you know what I mean?

Comment: You are right, the return is not working, the chosen value has to be access using `ex1.set` and `ex1.get()` method from `StringVar`

Answer (score 0):

The question is an example of why it is suggested that you learn classes first and use them to program a GUI  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_classes_objects.htm

```
import sys
if 3 == sys.version_info[0]:  ## 3.X is default if dual system
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x
else:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x

class StoreAVariable():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root=root
        self.ex1 = tk.StringVar(root)
        self.ex1.set("Pick Option")
        option = tk.OptionMenu(root, self.ex1, "one", "two", "three")
        option.pack()

        tk.Button(self.root, text="Please choose", command=self.choice).pack()

    def choice(self):
        self.chosen = self.ex1.get()

        ## the rest has nothing to do with storing a value
        print('chosen {}'.format(self.chosen))
        self.ex1.set(self.chosen)
        self.root.quit()
        # return chosen


root = tk.Tk()
RV=StoreAVariable(root)
root.mainloop()

print('-'*50)
print('After tkinter exits')
print('The final chosen value={}'.format(RV.chosen))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `global` statement *inside* the method:

```
def choice(self,option):
   global foo
   foo = option
```