# Storing user input text as a variable in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi, I want to be able to store user input text as a variable to use outside of the definition in Python. But it seems I can only access that variable in the definition itself. Any ideas on how I can make it accessible outside?

```
import tkinter

#Quit Window when ESC Pressed
def quit(event=None):
    window.destroy()

def GetCountry():
    global InputCountry
    InputCountry = UserInput.get()


#Create Main Window
window=tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (330, 80, 200, 150))
window.title("Select Country to Analyze")
window.bind('<Escape>', quit)

UserInput = tkinter.Entry(window)
UserInput.pack()

ButtonClick = tkinter.Button(window, text='Enter', command=GetCountry)
ButtonClick.pack(side='bottom')

print(InputCountry)
window.mainloop()
```

When I try to call the GetCountry or InputCountry it says they are not defined

Comment: I'd like to challenge your final paragraph. `print (GetCountry)` says for me `<function GetCountry at 0x1006d3e18>`, which sounds about correct.

Comment: Sorry, I guess that should be print(GetCountry()). If the user input "Spain" I want to store a variable = "Spain" in the main code, but can't seem to work out how this is done

Answer (score 0):

The variable InputCountry is not defined because it only exists in the scope of the *def GetCountry():* indent block. As for GetCountry, it is a function, thus you need to write this and it should work:

```
print(GetCountry())
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, I tried this but unfortunately this does not work. Is the print location fine above? Or does this need to be in another definition ?

Comment: The print location is fine, maybe try to store the returned value from the GetCountry() function in a variable before printing it but I'm not sure.

Comment: No luck i'm afraid :(

Comment: Try using the UserInput variable as a parameter of the GetCountry() function.

Comment: See my example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958535/python-getting-option-from-function/48979259#48979259 on how simple this is when using a class structure.

Answer (score 0):

That print statement would print *nothing* even if it was actually defined as it prints what's entered in the `UserInput` *before* anything is entered. Remove the useless lines of:

```
print(GetCountry)
print(InputCountry)
```

and add:

```
print(InputCountry)
```

in `def GetCountry():`'s scope.

Additionally, functions set as command callbacks *can't* really return. One workaround would be to attach the value wanted to be returned to the method object itself. Replace:

```
return InputCountry
```

with:

```
GetCountry.value = InputCountry
```

finally to have:

```
import tkinter

#Quit Window when ESC Pressed
def quit(event=None):
    window.destroy()

def GetCountry():
    InputCountry = UserInput.get()
    GetCountry.value = InputCountry
    print(InputCountry)


#Create Main Window
window=tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (330, 80, 200, 150))
window.title("Select Country to Analyze")
window.bind('<Escape>', quit)

UserInput = tkinter.Entry(window)
UserInput.pack()

ButtonClick = tkinter.Button(window, text='Enter', command=GetCountry)
ButtonClick.pack(side='bottom')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi. The issue is I am trying to create a global variable "InputCountry" for example, which I can use further down in the code. I guess by the reply you gave this is not possible as the variable stays within the def?

Comment: @JRH31 You _can_ create a global variable. `GetCountry.value` effectively _is_ a global variable. Alternatively you can make `InputCountry` a global variable as well by writing `global InputCountry` inside the method definiton.

Comment: I tried adding the global InputCountry in the def but when I try to print it outside the def I get "name 'InputCountry' is not defined" :( - I updated my code at top with what I have now

Comment: @JRH31 _Where_ outside?? Read the first part of my answer. Unless you're trying to print an _empty_ string, you're not supposed to be having that error.